# How can I replace a null value in a json document by a specific value with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file that contains `null`s as values for some keys, which I would like to replace with some specific value.

Given this input:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "rows": [
    {
      "panels": [
        {
          "title": "Panel1",
          "datasource": null
        },
        {
          "title": "Panel2",
          "datasource": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to have

```
{
  "id": null,
  "rows": [
    {
      "panels": [
        {
          "title": "Panel1",
          "datasource": "mydb"
        },
        {
          "title": "Panel2",
          "datasource": "mydb"
        }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

What I currently use is

```
sed 's/"datasource": null/"datasource": "mydb"/'
```

This produces the output I need, but I keep thinking that it is a shame to use `sed` for this job, when there are tools like `jq` that can work on JSON in a much better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to identify the objects you want to update. Since you want to set the null datasources of the panels to `"mydb"`, you could do this:

```
$ jq '.rows[].panels[].datasource //= "mydb"' input.json
```

If you want to update any `datasource` property on any object at any level, you could use `..` to recursively search for them.

```
$ jq '(.. | select(objects | has("datasource"))).datasource //= "mydb"' input.json
```

Comment: Is it only possible to do this when the complete path to the datasource field is fix?

Comment: There are ways to make it update any `datasource` property on any object at any level.  I'll add that example.

Comment: @JeffMercado great answer, what if a `datasource` is not `null`? how can we check if `key ==null` then `replace` with `""`

Comment: @dakait in that case, you can use the alternative operator (`//`). It will yield  the LHS if not null/false, otherwise the RHS.

Comment: @JeffMercado grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it is also quite easy to change all key values that are null (no matter where they occur) to some other value.  Versions of jq > 1.5 include a jq-defined filter, walk/1, which can be used (e.g. by copying and pasting) in other versions of jq as well.

For example, to change all key values that are null to 0 using walk/1:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.value //= 0) else . end)
```

Here is the jq-provided definition of walk/1:

```
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream**, **reduce** and **setpath** to set any leaf `datasource` attribute whose value is `null` to `"mydb"`.

```
reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
  .
; if $p[-1] == "datasource" and $v == null then setpath($p; "mydb") else . end
)
```