# Filter by values using ./jq

Tags: json, jq

Given the input of sizes:

```
[
  {
    "stock": 1,
    "sales": 0,
    "sizes": [
      {
        "countries": ["at", "be", "ch", "cy", "de", "ee", "es", "fi", "gr", "ie", "lu", "lv", "nl", "pl", "pt", "se", "si", "sk"],
        "size": "EU 45,5"
      },
      {
        "countries": ["it"],
        "size": "EU 45,5"
      },
      {
        "countries": ["fr"],
        "size": "EU 45,5"
      },
      {
        "countries": ["gb"],
        "size": "EU 45,5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I will like to get the same structure without the ones that `countries` hasn't "de" (Germany) and remove the field complete. Expected something like this:

```
[
  {
    "stock": 1,
    "sizes": [
      {
        "size": "EU 45,5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this:

```
map(.sizes[] |= select(.countries | join(",") | contains("de"))) | map({ stock, sizes })
```

But the filter is not working properly, throwing `jq: error (at <stdin>:48): Cannot iterate over null (null)`.

Tried `has`, `in`, `contains`, `inside` and nothing seems to work.

Also, how can I filter which field appears? With `map({ stock, sizes })` countries still there. Can I do something like `map({ stock, sizes: { size } })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that answers your main question -- if you can't see how it works, try breaking it up into separate pieces:

```
map( .sizes |= map( select(.countries | index("de") ) | del(.countries) ))
```

Regarding the selection of fields, you can use del/1 as above, or sometimes simply using an expression such as `{key1, key2}` will do the trick.  Consider also this function and the following example:

```
def query(queryobject):
  with_entries( select( .key as $key | queryobject | has( $key ) ));
```

Example:

```
$ jq -c -n '{"a": 1, "b": null, "c":3} | query( {a,b,d} )'
{"a":1,"b":null}
```

Comment: Great. What if I need to query very deep JSON structure. Like: `{"a":[{"b":[{"c":true,"nc":false}],"nb":false},{"b":[{"c":true,"nc":false}],"nb":false}],"na":false}`? I'll `'. | del(.na) | del(.a[].nb) | del(.a[].b[].nc)'`? Or there is a nicer way?

Comment: Please see the answer using "walk/1" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128365 or ask a separate question on SO.